# CSS styles ignored on one row in ItemTemplate

Tags: css, asp.net, formview

My layout looks great in Visual Studio until I click Start without debugging at which time my styles in one row of my table within my ItemTemplate are ignored. All the other 9 rows look great, as does the PagerTemplate. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
<asp:Table CssClass="fvFooter" ID="EditButton" runat="server">
  <asp:TableCell CssClass="editButtonsRow">
  <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CssClass="btnEdits" runat="server" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" CssClass="btnEdits" runat="server" Text="Add" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Add" />                           
  <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" CssClass="btnEdits" runat="server" Text="Remove" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Remove" />
```

Here are the styles

```
.fvFooter {
background-color: #F0F0F0;
height: 3em;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-top: .25em;
width: 55.75em;
}
.editButtonsRow {
background-color: #F0F0F0;   
margin-left: 2px;
margin-top: .25em;
padding-bottom: .5em;
padding-left: 41em;
padding-top: .5em;
width: 14.75em;
}
.btnEdits {
float: left;
font-weight: bold;    
margin-left: .5em;
width: 5em;
}
```

Here is the generated HTML

```
<table id="DetailContentPlaceHolder_fvQuickView_EditButton" class="fvFooter">
  <tr id="DetailContentPlaceHolder_fvQuickView_TableRow10">
    <td class="editButtonsRow">
      <input type="submit" name="ctl00$DetailContentPlaceHolder$fvQuickView$Button1" value="Edit" id="DetailContentPlaceHolder_fvQuickView_Button1" class="btnEdits" />
      <input type="submit" name="ctl00$DetailContentPlaceHolder$fvQuickView$Button2" value="Add" id="DetailContentPlaceHolder_fvQuickView_Button2" class="btnEdits" />
      <input type="submit" name="ctl00$DetailContentPlaceHolder$fvQuickView$Button3" value="Remove" id="DetailContentPlaceHolder_fvQuickView_Button3" class="btnEdits" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: if you inspect that row in Chrome dev tools (F12), are those styles overwritten or striked through and other styles applied?

Comment: In Chrome dev tools the styles shown are not current. I've edited the css file and saved but that's not what shows in Chrome.